# How to simultaneously iterate and modify list, set, etc?

Tags: python

In my program I have **many** lines where I need to both iterate over a something **and** modify it in that same `for` loop.

However, I know that modifying the thing over which you're iterating is bad because it *may* - probably **will** - result in an undesired result.

So I've been doing something like this:

```
for el_idx, el in enumerate(theList):
    if theList[el_idx].IsSomething() is True:
        theList[el_idx].SetIt(False)
```

Is this the best way to do this?

Comment: You're not actually modifying the list in this code. `theList[idx].SetIt(False)` might modify a list element, but it wouldn't touch the list. You don't need to iterate by indices here.

Comment: That said, when you think you do need to modify something while iterating over it, the best course of action is usually to change things so you don't need to do that. Frequently, that's by computing a modified version of the list/set/whatever and then replacing the original with the new version.

Comment: @user2357112 yes that's the easy way but what about memory? In my current work, that's not an issue but how would you do it if it were an issue?

Comment: @user2357112 If you `.append()` or `.add()` an item from one list/set/whatever to another, will Python be smart and use shared memory?

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. Be appreciated if you could show me example of undesired result.  And another thing why `el_idx`, `el` are declared without using?

Comment: @Adrian You give some solution but don't show an obvious problem. Please show how to get undesired result?

Answer (score 1):

This is a conceptual misunderstanding.

It is dangerous to modify the list itself from within the iteration, because of the way Python translates the loop to lower level code. This can cause unexpected side effects during the iteration, there's a good example here :

https://unspecified.wordpress.com/2009/02/12/thou-shalt-not-modify-a-list-during-iteration/

But modifying mutable objects stored in the list is acceptable, and common practice.

I suspect that you're thinking that because the list is made up of those objects, that modifying those objects modifies the list. This is understandable - it's just not how it's normally thought of. If it helps, consider that the list only really contains references to those objects. When you modify the objects within the loop - you are merely *using* the list to modify the objects, not *modifying* the list itself.

What you should not do is add or remove items from the list during the iteration.

Comment: Yes that is my use case - modifying the elements but not adding to or removing elements.

Comment: But in the case when I am doing both - adding/deleting + modifying - is there a better/cleaner way to do it than with indices?

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing why you want to do it. You could defer the adding / deleting until after the iteration. You could pop from the list until it is exhausted, and create a new list as you go (maybe in a generator function) as if it were a queue. You could just use indexes. You could create a custom wrapper around the list that meets your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be unclear to me. But if we talk about harmful of modifying list during a `for` loop iteration in Python. I can think about two scenarios.

**First**, You modify some elements in list that suppose to be used on the next round of computation as its original value.

e.g. You want to write a program that have such inputs and outputs like these.

Input:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Expected output:

```
[1, 3, 6, 10] #[1, 1 + 2, 1 + 2 + 3, 1 + 2 + 3 + 4]
```

But...you write a code in this way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4]

for idx, n in enumerate(mylist):
    mylist[idx] = sum(mylist[:idx + 1])
print mylist
```

Result is:

```
[1, 3, 7, 15] # undesired result
```

**Second**, you make some change on size of list during a `for` loop iteration.

e.g. From [python-delete-all-entries-of-a-value-in-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32263634/python-delete-all-entries-of-a-value-in-list/32263821):

```
>>> s=[1,4,1,4,1,4,1,1,0,1]
>>> for i in s:
...   if i ==1: s.remove(i)
... 
>>> s
[4, 4, 4, 0, 1]
```

The example shows the undesired result that raised from side-effect of changing size in list. This obviously shows you that `for` each loop in Python can not handle list with dynamic size in a proper way. Below, I show you some simple way to overcome this problem:

```
  #!/usr/bin/env python

  s=[1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 1, 0, 1]
  list_size=len(s)
  i=0

  while i!=list_size:
      if s[i]==1:
          del s[i]
          list_size=len(s)
      else:
          i=i + 1

  print s
```

Result:

```
[4, 4, 4, 0]
```

**Conclusion**: It's definitely not harmful to modify any elements in list during a loop iteration, if you don't 1) make change on size of list 2) make some side-effect of computation by your own.

Answer (score -1):

you could get index first

```
idx = [ el_idx for el_idx, el in enumerate(theList) if el.IsSomething() ]
[ theList[i].SetIt(False) for i in idx ]
```

Comment: I don't understand what that does. I understand list comprehensions but not double-comprehensions.

Comment: @Adrian first line get index which el.IsSomehing() is True. second line is set value to those elements based on first line's result