# IndexError: list index out of range on simple for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I don't know what is wrong with my code. I'm getting this error but my code looks right to me. `len(song_json['Lyrics'])` has a length  of 44.

```
captions = ['[Intro]', '[Verse]', '[Chorus]']
for word in captions:
    for i in range(len(song_json['Lyrics'])):
        if word == song_json['Lyrics'][i]:
            song_json['Lyrics'].remove(word)
        else:
            pass
```

**IndexError: list index out of range**

Comment: Can you provide the `song_json`?

Comment: Your `for i` loop is going up to the initial value of `len(song_json)`, but the length is reduced each time you do `song_json['Lyrics'].remove(word)`, so you run off the end of the list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python - how to simultaneously iterate and modify list, set, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38677708/python-how-to-simultaneously-iterate-and-modify-list-set-etc)

Comment: check out the `filter` function

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to remove anything from `song_json['Lyrics']` which is in `captions`. You could do this instead:

```
song_json['Lyrics'] = [lyric for lyric in song_json['Lyrics'] if lyric not in captions]
```

Or using filter:

```
song_json['Lyrics'] = list(filter(lambda l: l not in captions, song_json['Lyrics']))
```

Comment: This is a good answer. Note that it assigns a (one-time!) generator, rather than a list. Consider assigning `... = list(filter( ... ))`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input everyone! This is what I changed my code to

```
captions = ['[Intro]', '[Verse]', '[Chorus]']
for word in captions:
    for i in song_json['Lyrics']:
        if word == i:
            song_json['Lyrics'].remove(word)
        else:
            pass
```